# Advanced Auto-Layout in Xcode 6

Tags: swift, xcode6, autolayout

I've build this view in inferred size in Xcode 6 -

[image]

Every button is in an image view. When i run the app it looks terrible.
I know a little bit about auto-layout but i can't make it look good.

Any tips?

Comment: Please be more specific about what happens and what doesn't and what you have tried to solve the problem. The WWDC videos about auto-layout are very helpful. So maybe you should watch them first to know more about auto layout and not only a little bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the only way to help you is to suggest you grabbing a good auto-layout tutorial. I guess this one is perfect in your case: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IwSTXY0awng

Hope you will get a better understanding of using auto-layout.

Nevertheless if you want some immediate tips, here are some. Remember that I can only guess how the appearance should look like on other screen, it all depends on your vision:

1)Set the trailing space and leading space to superview for the blue rectangle. Don't forget to pin it on the top as well

2) Set leading space for YT and FB buttons, the first should be pinned to the blue rectangle while the latter should be pinned to the bottom of subview.

3) Do the analogy with yellow and green one, but set the trailing space instead of leading space

4) Twitter button should be pinned to fb icon and to the bottom of subview